# Show the Real IP in the Logs of a Keter Managed App

Tags: yesod

I would like to display the actual IP of the request as opposed to the localhost in my log files. Since Keter manages the Nginx config I am not sure what I need to change to get the real ip.

This is what I see now:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2014:09:25:08 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 - "" 
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keter hasn't been based on nginx for quite a while now. Recent versions of Keter set the `X-Real-IP` request header to containing the client's IP address (see [issue #8](https://github.com/snoyberg/keter/issues/8)), which you can use in wai-extra via [IPAddrSource](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-extra-2.0.3.1/docs/Network-Wai-Middleware-RequestLogger.html#t%3aIPAddrSource).

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I am using Keter version 1.0.1 but I am probably using too old a version of Wai-extra (1.3). I am thinking of doing a system upgrade so I am fully caught up to most of the changes. With the latest version of yesod, will a new scaffolded project automatically set the right logging params or I need to manually add them? I see the logging code here: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-bin-1.2.5.2/src/hsfiles/simple.hsfiles is different from my Foundation.hs which was generated with an older version.

Comment: Sorry meant to say Application.hs. I just created a new dev environment with the latest version of the platform and the logging code seem to match the link I had above. So hopefully that will do the trick.